# Can I use JavaScript fetch() to insert an inline svg in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a function that inserts an inline svg in the DOM using XMLHttpRequest() and I'm wondering if I can do the same function using fetch(). The function is...

```js
el = document.querySelector('#foo')
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', 'bar.svg', true)

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState !== 4) return
  if (this.status !== 200) return
  el.innerHTML = this.responseText
}
request.send()
// bar.svg is inserted in element with ID 'foo'
```

So, is it possible to modernize this function into something like...

```
fetch('bar.svg').then(...)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can. I think the following should work:

```
fetch('bar.svg')
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(text => {
        el.innerHTML = text;
    })
    .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

The second `then` is for resolving the `.text()`, which "takes a Response stream and reads it to completion" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Response)) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) Eng).

Comment: I get an eslint error (needs // eslint-disable-next-line no-unsanitized/property) with similar code...which seems excessive, but is it?

Comment: Can we insert inline svg without the network call? Is there any way?

Answer (score -3):

Yea, fetch returns a promise.So you can use then() and catch(error) to catch error. But be aware of **Browser compatibility**